# convert ruby array to regular string

Tags: ruby, regex, text-processing

i have an array like this

```
text_arr = ["hello","how","are","you"]
```

and i want to convert this to string like this

```
text = "hello how are you"
```

How can i do this with Ruby ?

Comment: Just do `text_arr.join ' '`

Answer (score 3):

Try this one

```
text = text_arr.join(' ')
```